# Can I deploy SQL Server Express with my desktop application just like builtin database?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, deployment, sql-server-express

Can I deploy SQL Server Express with my desktop application just like builtin database?
Because I don't want my client to set up separately SQL Server Express! Is it easy to integrate SQL Server Express into my desktop application ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlexpress/archive/2004/07/04/172952.aspx):

> Can I redistribute SQL Express?
>
> SQL Server Express will be free to use
>   and redistribute.  The only
>   requirement that we have is that you
>   register to redistribute the product.
>   The reason we require registration for
>   redistribution is that we want to
>   ensure that we can get critical
>   security/product information to
>   ISVs/partners if necessary.
>
> -Euan Garden
>   Product Unit Manager
>   SQL Server Tools

Take a look on how to do it:

[How to deploy SQL Server 2008 Express as a prerequisite with ClickOnce](http://blogs.msdn.com/manisblog/archive/2008/12/22/how-to-deploy-sql-server-2008-express-as-clickonce-prerequisite.aspx)

[ClickOnce Deployment: Customizing SQL Server Express](http://aspalliance.com/714)

[How To Install Sql Server Express In Package Deployment With Different Instance Name](http://www.trap17.com/index.php/Install-Sql-Server-Express-Package-Deployment-Instance_t60470.html)

Answer (score 1):

As said by MS:
"To obtain rights to redistribute SQL Server 2005 Express Edition, you must register with Microsoft. "
The link is: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/express-redistribute.aspx

Hope this will help.

By the way, you may be interested in MS SQL Server Compact : http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx
It's embedded dbms. It's free but also need a distribution rights registration:
http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact-redistribute.aspx

Comment: Sorry, at first i thought you have a license question... But my reply  may be helpful, so i'll not delete it.