# Register for SQL Server Express redistribution

Tags: licensing, sql-server-express, redistributable

We would like to redistribute SQL Server Express with our application, and according to the following links:
[MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/01dbc5c3-b5fe-42d4-9eb9-91683cf8285b?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Profile/u/create?referrer=http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlexpress/thread/01dbc5c3-b5fe-42d4-9eb9-91683cf8285b),
[SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442635/can-i-deploy-sql-server-express-with-my-desktop-application-just-like-builtin-da/2442660#2442660)
it is necessary to register at Microsoft before. Unfortunately the link to the mentioned [registration form](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/in/express/redistregister.aspx) is broken and I cannot find a registration form on the MS websites. Has anyone done the registration recently and can help me with a working link?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with SQL Server 2012 the redistribution rights are built into the SQL Server Express license, and registration is no longer required to redistribute this version of SQL Server Express.

Comment: The installer presents the license during the installation. It also gets copied somewhere under Program Files, but I don't have it installed now, so I can't give you the exact location.

Comment: Try looking here (C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\License Terms) or here (http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29693) or here (http://www.google.com/search?q=Download+Microsoft+SQL+Server+Express+License+Terms).