# MICROSOFT SQL SERVER LICENSE TERMS

Tags: sql-server, licensing

I developed software which requires the MSSQL database in the backend. So I need to include the Microsoft sql setup within my application setup file. But when referring the license terms and the Microsoft’s knowledge base article, found conflicts as bellow.

In the license terms under the ‘Scope of License’ there mentioned “You may not publish the software for others to copy”.

But in the knowledge base “https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd981032(v=sql.100).aspx” I found “Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express is a robust, freely distributable relational database management system”.

So by seeing these 2 statements I am confused whether I can include sql server setup in my application or not. Please any help would be appreciated.

**Edit**: 
Sql server used is MSSQL server 2008 (since it supports windows XP)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redistribution of SQL Server Express is available for free.

[Register for SQL Server Express redistribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925740/register-for-sql-server-express-redistribution)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using server 2008, But still in the license of sql server 2012 there is same sentence i mentioned above “You may not publish the software for others to copy” under ‘Scope of License'

Comment: Did you try SQLite3?

Comment: No. My application is developed for MS SQL server and that needs MS SQL only. Out of that, my confusion is whether I can embed the SQL server express setup in my application or not.

Answer (score 1):

> SQL Server comes with different editions like Express, Devloper, Standard..etc.
> Among all these editions, Express edition is free for learning and developing small applications.

Reference: 
http://www.quackit.com/sql_server/sql_server_2008/tutorial/sql_server_editions.cfm
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144275(v=sql.100).aspx