# Include SQL Server Express in setup project

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I create project in Visual Studio. My app use `.mdf` files. I created a setup project using InstallShield. On my computer where I developed my app, setup works just fine!

But when I install app on another machine I get an error

> you need install SQL Server Express

How to embed SQL Server Express into my setup project?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL Server on your computer, Visual Studio can not embed this. Go to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver2014express.aspx, download and install. I'm not sure if you can get it without a Microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

By using `.mdf` you got a *dependency* on SQL Server Express (at least). You might want to pack your database to a server and have your app just use client libraries or you could switch to SQLite or something with less footprint.

Also take a look here how to bundle your setup with SQL Server Express:
[Can I deploy SQL Server Express with my desktop application just like builtin database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442635/can-i-deploy-sql-server-express-with-my-desktop-application-just-like-builtin-da)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio publishing tool can do that. If you're required to use InstallShield, there's a guy who ensembled a video guide: http://www.installationdeveloper.com/3356/how-to-install-sql-server-2008-express-r2-in-installshield/

Comment: this link is not working anymore.

Comment: Are you complaining about a link posted in 2015 pointing to a resource from 2008 and not available in 2022? Seriously?