# How to create a C# program setup wizard, containing a SQL Server connected database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-2008, database-connection, connection-string

I am developing a C# Windows Forms project in Visual Studio which contains a SQL Server database.

Everything is working great I have connection string saved in `Properties.Settings`... but when I install program on a different computer, it doesn't have data from database.

Of course I know that I have to add database to the other computer too, but can I do it without installing complete SQL Server?

[image]

Here is a picture of my connection string in settings.

I know that there are a lot similar questions like this out there, but more than I am reading those answers more lost I am.

Thank you for every clean explanation and answer or just link on great tutorial!
Have a nice day!

Comment: SQLExpress is not really a good solution because, like you indicated, it will need to be installed on the target machines.  You should look into other portable database solutions, like SQLite.

Comment: See [Include SQL Server Express in setup project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30016652/include-sql-server-express-in-setup-project)

Comment: I've heard about SQL Lite, but can I just switch between them so I won't need to do any changes on my database?

Comment: If use of a SQL Server database is required, the LocalDb is the way to go. LocalDb is the smallest version of SQL server intended for local use. You can install it with its own installer bundled with yours. Google "localdb install with database" or similar.

Comment: you can use compact edition which is also used as default database for most of solutions

Comment: @a-man Compact edition is deprecated since 2013