# How to encrypt MS SQL attached mdf file (user instance SQL Express)

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption

In my application I am using SQL Express/ LocalDB with an attached mdf file. 
The following is an example connection string:

```
"data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|database.mdf;Trusted_Connection=Yes; User Instance=true;Connection Timeout=30"
```

I need to encrypt database so it is not easily accessible from a third party.

Transparent Data Encryption is the perfect fit, but it is not an option, because it is only for enterprise edition of SQL Server.

I have found similar solutions for SQLite, where it appears to be possibly to hook the encryption/ decryption algorithm ([sqlcipher.net](https://sqlcipher.net) and others).

There are also solutions for MSSQL server, which are rather expensive (for my case) and work only on normal databases (not user instance attached mdf files).

Finally, symmetric encryption is possible and supported (at least on SQL Express) but it means major application changes.

I am looking for an option to encrypt the whole database (or the data in several tables) with the least effort possible. 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Update**

Encryption of data is needed for regulatory purposes (GDPR) in order to protect "data at rest".

The application is desktop app and will work on Windows.

Comment: Does it have to be MS-SQL?

Comment: Yes, MSSQL Express or LocalDB is a requirement as the application is mostly developed

Comment: when you say "LocalDB" you just mean on the PC... right?  if data protection was required what was planned during design phase if its mostly developed

Comment: Correct - desktop application working on Windows. The requirement for encryption appeared late (very late) in the development phase.

Comment: have you considered sql compact? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171955(v=sql.110).aspx - its local, it allows for encryption

Comment: [Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine)  is [available in all editions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/) starting with SQL Server 2016 SP1. The same with partitioning, compression and other features that used to be available only for Enterprise SKUs. Always Encrypted will encrypt specific columns, not the entire database like TDE

Comment: Does the entire database have to be *encrypted*? Does the customer understand the cost and the *management requirements*? As in `lose the key, lose all data and backups`? There are various mechanisms that can be used to prevent unauthorised acces. Never mind that in a *desktop* application, only the logged-in use can read the data. Unless the disk is stolen, in which case the best defence is full-disk encryption with BitLocker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, keep in mind this kind of stuff will drain your application performance because you'll be encrypting and decrypting data on every read and write. Having said that, here is a solution:

You can enable Always Encrypted in your database to encrypt sensitive data. From the docs:

> Always Encrypted is a feature designed to protect sensitive data, such as credit card numbers or national identification numbers (for example, U.S. social security numbers), stored in Azure SQL Database or SQL Server databases. Always Encrypted allows clients to encrypt sensitive data inside client applications and never reveal the encryption keys to the Database Engine ( SQL Database or SQL Server).

Note about performance:

> Because Always Encrypted is a client-side encryption technology, most of performance overheads are observed on the client side, not in the database. Apart from the cost of encryption and decryption operations, the other sources of performance overheads on the client side are: Additional round trips to the database to retrieve metadata for query parameters.
>   Calls to a column master key store to access a column master key.

I'm not sure if you can achieve that using the embedded database file. Try to open it using SSMS and follow the guides below.

Assuming you're installing your application through a installer, you can embed an SQL Express instance inside your installer. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2442659/6490459) answer for more info.

Also, by using the embedded SQL Express installation, you can enable Entity Framework automatic migrations in your project.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine#Anchor_5) is how you enable Always Encrypted in your database and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider) is a running sample from Microsoft Documentation.

Comment: If you are willing to consider a third party product, there are at least two that can provide TDE to SQL Express. Ours Is [Encryptionizer for SQL Server](https://netlibsecurity.com/products/sql-server-encryption/) and another is DBEncrypt. They work differently though: Encryptionizer sits between the SQL Server process and the OS, while DBEncrypt injects itself into the SQL Server process in memory using that old Detours SDK (no longer available SFAIK).